# Confusion: Endless arrays within arrays inside my class' data members. Bad class design?

Tags: php, javascript, oop

Let's assume there are three classes:

**Sponsor**{`id`[int], `name`[string], `sponsoredProjects`[array of **Project** objects]}

**Project**{`id`[int], `name`[string], `desc`[string], `sponsors`[array of **Sponsor** objects]}

**School**{`id`[int], `name`[string], `projectsDone`[array of **Project** objects}

I'm stuck between **Sponsor**'s `sponsoredProjects` and **Project**'s `sponsors`.

Theoretically, if I create a **Project** then I need to create the **Sponsor** for it too. If I create **Sponsor** then I need to create the **Project** for it too.

So, that would result in endless arrays of **Project** with **Sponsor** within them with **Project** within them with **Sponsors** within them and etc. Am I right? Same problem should apply to **School** too since they have array of **Project** which have array of **Sponsor** which have array of **Project** and so on.

***If so then how should I avoid this flaw?***

My goal is to create all these objects from returned multiple SQL results temporarily, which in turn I will send to JavaScript page.

```
final class Sponsor{
    private $_id;
    private $_name;
    private $_projects;

    public function __construct($id, $name, Project $projects){
        $this->setSponsor($id, $name, $projects);
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->_id;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->_name;
    }

    public function getProjects(){
        return $this->_projects;
    }

    private function setId($id){
        $this->_id = $id;
    }

    private function setName($name){
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    private function setProject(Project $projects){
        $this->_projects = array();
        foreach($projects as $val){
            array_push($this->_projects, $val);
        }
    }

    private function setSponsor($id, $name, Project $projects){
        $this->setId($id);
        $this->setName($name);
        $this->setProjects($projects);
    }
}

final class Project{
    private $_id;
    private $_name;
    private $_desc;
    private $_sponsors;

    public function __construct($id, $name, $desc, Sponsor $sponsors){
        $this->setProject($id, $name, $desc, $sponsors);
    }

    private function setId($id){
        $this->_id = $id;
    }

    private function setName($name){
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    private function setDesc($desc){
        $this->_desc = $desc;
    }

    private function setSponsors(Sponsor $sponsors){
        $this->_sponsors = array();
        foreach($sponsors as $obj){
            $id = $obj->getId();
            $name = $obj->getName();
            $projects = $obj->getProjects();
            array_push($this->_sponsors, new Sponsor($id, $name, Project $this));
        }
    }

    private function setProject($id, $name, $desc, Sponsor $sponsors){
        $this->setId($id);
        $this->setName($name);
        $this->setDesc($desc);
        $this->setSponsors($sponsors);
    }
}

final class School{

    private $_id;
    private $_name; 
    private $_projectsDone;

    public function __construct($id, $name, Project $projects){
        $this->setSchool($id, $name, $projects);
    }

    private function setId($id){
        $this->_id = $id;
    }

    private function setName($name){
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    private function setProjectsDone($projects){
        $this->_projectsDone = array();
        foreach($projectsDone as $val){
            $this->{_projectsDone}[] = $val;
        }
    }

    public function setSchool($id, $name, $projectsDone){
        $this->setId($id);
        $this->setName($name);
        $this->setProjectsDone($projectsDone);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a [circular reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) problem. Instead of each object holding an array of the objects it's related to, try keeping arrays of their ids and look up the related entity when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with having objects hold reference back and forth between each other. It's very common, and its a normal(reflexive) relation on a set. For example, the DOM  in javascript...an Element node knows its children, and its children know their parent.

Obviously you need to take care when constructing and initializing them, as there's a little bit of a chicken & egg issue, but the check just boils down to

```
if relation to object not established
    establish()
```

You mentioned you store this info in a database. You can probably even avoid the check. You probably have, for example, the following tables:

```
Sponsor
Project
School
SponsoredProjects - many to many relation
SchoolProjectsDone - many to many relation
```

Construct the Sponsor, Project, and School objects, and then loop over the relations in the SponsoredProjects and SchoolProjectsDone tables, associating the objects.